# How to get JSON from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a button when clicking which we get a new user using ajax.

```
const getNewUser = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://randomuser.me/api/', true);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      const userData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      usersInformation(userData);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Error: ${xhr.status} ${xhr.statusText}`);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

I also have a function that generates an object with data about the user and calls a function to send this data to users.php, in order to later insert  data into a SQL table.

```
const usersInformation = (user) => {
  const userData = user.results[0],
    obj = {
      name: capitalizeFirstLetter(userData.name.first),
      lastname: capitalizeFirstLetter(userData.name.last),
      city: capitalizeFirstLetter(userData.location.city),
      phone: userData.phone,
      logoUrl: userData.picture.medium,
    };
  postData(obj);
};

const postData = (data) => {
  const stringifyData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '../users.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(stringifyData);
}
```

Data is sent:

> XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/users.php"

[Network tab in Ghrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBsN.png)

But I can not handle them, as I did not try.

```
<?php
$obj = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo($obj->name);
?>
```

And using $ _POST also tried it ((

Any idea how fix this?

Thanks in advance!

> P.S I'm using Apache24 + PHP-7.2.1

Comment: Did you try to use `json_decode($obj);`?

Comment: you have to deserialise the JSON to an object - see IncredibleHat's comment above for the function you need.

Comment: I'm trying using like this `if ( ( $obj = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) ) ) !== NULL ) {
    echo $obj->name;
}`     Not happend!! !!

Comment: Please do a `var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input') );` before you do anything else, and add the content here in your question. It may not really be a full valid json string.

Comment: I get message like is: string(0) ""

Comment: Then nothing is coming in to PHP. Your issue then is with the javascript.

Comment: But were?  I send JSON  `{"name":"Kimberly","lastname":"Jenkins","city":"Lusk","phone":"071-450-2723","logoUrl":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/19.jpg"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Note the `true` second argument.

[Documentation for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Not happend=(  Instead I get that   
**Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in C:\Server\data\htdocs\users.php on line 3**

Comment: As others mentioned, it is because nothing is being sent to the PHP script. Show your sending code in the question and we can help more.